# Reducing a fraction with the denominator as a root.

Tags: fractions

I have always been terrible with these, but how does $\frac{-36}{\sqrt{3^5}}$ equal $\frac{-4}{\sqrt{3}}$ ?

completely butchered the latex... I have -36/(root3)^(5) where the exponent is in the denominator. This equals -4/root3.

Comment: You were close on the $\LaTeX$, but need to enclose it in dollar signs.  You can look at my edit to see.  Also \frac and \over are redundant.   The newest edit uses forward slashes where you should have backslashes.

Comment: Note $(\sqrt3)^2=3$, and $a^5=a^2a^2a$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{3^{5}}=\sqrt{3^{4}\cdot3}=3^{2}\sqrt{3}=9\sqrt{3}$ .
Also note $\frac{36}{9}=4$